# Is there a docker image which is similar (or the same) as AWS EC2 AMI?

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ami

I want to test something which I later deploy to Amazon AWS using the default AMI. Is there a Docker image which I can test with, that has the same "content" as Amazon base AMI?

Comment: Amazon have an [official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/amazonlinux/) now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon now have an official container image

https://hub.docker.com/_/amazonlinux/

```
→ docker run -ti amazonlinux bash
Unable to find image 'amazonlinux:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/amazonlinux
c9141092a50d: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:2010c88ac1e7c118d61793eec71dcfe0e276d72b38dd86bd3e49da1f8c48bf54
Status: Downloaded newer image for amazonlinux:latest
bash-4.2# yum search aws-apitools-ec2
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
amzn-main/latest                                                                                 | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-main/latest/group                                                                           |  35 kB     00:01     
amzn-main/latest/primary_db                                                                      | 3.5 MB     00:22     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                              | 2.3 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest/group                                                                        |  35 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest/updateinfo                                                                   | 362 kB     00:01     
amzn-updates/latest/primary_db                                                                   | 498 kB     00:03     
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
============================================ N/S matched: aws-apitools-ec2 =============================================
aws-apitools-ec2.noarch : The API tools serve as the client interface to the Amazon EC2 web service. Use these tools to
                        : register and launch instances, manipulate security groups, and more.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a host using

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 myhost
```

it will use the following base image `ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20160516.1`. This is as of today. They keep updating it. The ami depends on which AWS region you're in. In my case (ap-southeast-2) it's `ami-f4361997`.

I believe the ami for a given version of ubuntu can be found here. https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/ Although they only list the latest ami's and AWS is behind a few months (20160516 vs 20160830).

Comment: Thanks but I do not search for the Docker image but the AMI base